# can't import database to the server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I always import the database file to the server with the way that I'm using again. But this time when I want to do this I get this following error :

> SQL query:
>
> phpMyAdmin SQL Dump SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>
> SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"' at line 1

Does anyone can help me to solve this problem? I always use this method but this time I have this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the part of your dumping sql file until database selection?

Comment: Which operating system are you working with? If you're using windows which development environment are you using? Wamp or ....

Comment: @aliboy38 I'm working with windows and using wampserver

Comment: @afroozhashemzadegani Nice. so see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it seems the problem is because of your `MYSQL` version. As I asked you in the comment below of your question, it seems you are using `WAMPSERVER`. So because of your `WAMPSERVER` version it has different version for your MYSQL.

The server you're trying to import may has newer version of `MYSQL`. So you can simply update your `WAMP` and then you have updated your `MYSQL` version. Then try to import them to the server. so you can fix this problem.

Hope it helps

Always try to be update

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's gonna help someone anymore, but I have face the same problem and found a solution.

@afroozhashemzadegani - as You can see, there's an additional character after the "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO" string in SQL error message.

[@afroozhashemzadegani error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIwcn.png)

I had the same character in my error message:

[My error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH9Tt.png)

So I opened it in hex:

[copied error in hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/035Mr.png)

When I deleted this guy, everything worked fine. Honestly, I don't know where it came from, as it was already there when I exported database. Anyway, it didn't look like if it mattered on which version of target MySQL server I tried to import it. The error was always the same. It didn't also look like if it mattered what was the first line of SQL code, as when I deleted some of the code on the top, the same error occured for the next portion of executable code.

Answer (score 1):

SET SQL_MODE=”NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO”; happens when different version of mysql is being used. When you are transfering from one server to another you should keep in mind the versions of database use in a new environment especially the mysql.

The fix is as follow. simply delete the following lines from your database and you are done

SET SQL_MODE=”NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO”;

visit https://www.drupal.org/node/164401

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the import file was edited with a text editor which discretely added a BOM (byte order mark) on saving. Windows´ Notepad does this for example, and since you work with Windows this a highly likely scenario.

Solution:
Get a professional text editor (PSPad, Notepad++, whatever, but not Windows Notepad) or Hex editor, check for and remove the first 3 bytes (HEX: EF BB BF), save the file without these BOM bytes - importer should have no problem anymore.

Background:
The BOM fools the importer, the first - gets eaten and the importer no longer recognizes the first comment as such.
[Wikipedia about BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861462):

Answer (score 0):

`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` is off by default. it is very **rare to actually have it turned on at the server level**, and is usually used only in SQL dumps.

NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO only affects what happens during an insert. turning the mode off does not affect rows that are already in a table.

**Problem:** the mySQL version I was importing into was older - mySQLversion I exported from was 5.0, mySQL version I was importing into was 3.23.56 so in phpMyAdmin's export tab I selected from the "SQL compatibility mode" drop down list "MYSQL323" and the import then work sucessfully.